# TypeScript type definition for a list of keys from an array of objects

Tags: typescript

I have a constant (read only) set of data in an application that serves as a mapping between API values and UI values.

```
// data
const mapping = [{key: 1, value: 'Cat'}, {key: 2, value: 'Dog'}, {key: 3, value: 'Cow'}]
```

What I **effectively** want:

```
type AllowedAnimals = 'Cat' | 'Dog' | 'Cow';
```

What I have tried:

```
type AllowedAnimals = typeof mapping[number]['value'];
```

However, TypeScript simply interprets this as a `string` instead of my literal values. I've also looked into TS's lookup types (keyof) but I'm not sure that fits.

A workaround solution would be to simply re-declare all of the values but that approach is not DRY.

What am I missing? Is this even possible?

Comment: Presumably `mapping` is inferred as `{ key: number, value: string }[]`? In general when you want more specific types `as const` can help.

Comment: `as const` was the answer here